# What can I do with vinyl tile where the floor edge is open, like at a descending staircase?

Tags: installation, stairs, vinyl-flooring

I'm thinking of installing vinyl tile in one floor of my house, but I have two places where the floor does not meet a wall, for example, where a staircase begins to descend.  What sort of elegant options are there in cases like this?

Answer (score 3):

[aluminum stair nosing](https://www.google.com/#q=aluminum+stair+nosing) –Google

[image]

<sub>[source](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000I1TKM0)</sub>

Comment: Oh so elegant!!

Answer (score 3):

I **do** happen to like the aluminum, but would stained and varnished oak stair nosing be elegant enough?

[image]

Comment: This is what I was going to suggest. To add a bit more detail on the application, I would mount a new one, or raise the old one  slightly higher so it finishes above the tile. Add the proper shims under it to raise it up and secure it with a good grade of construction adhesive and a few well placed nails. If the original is used and it was held in  place with 2 1/2" nails, reset it with 3" nails in the same holes. The larger nails with larger diameter should snug everything up again like new. The construction adhesive will seal the deal.

Comment: Thanks, Jimmy.  I like the look of this better than the aluminum.  The tiles I'm hoping to go with are a slate template, so this may look quite good together depending on the pattern.